# Mulitple sql select or one combined select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a multiple language table for texts. (Columns: hu, en, de, sr, ...)
The rows contain texts.
Every text in the website stored in this table. So I have a lot of select queries in different places.

Which is better, faster?

1. Lots of select queries with only 1-1 result

   ```
   SELECT en FROM langtexts WHERE id='41';
   SELECT en FROM langtexts WHERE id='63';
   SELECT en FROM langtexts WHERE id='89';
   ```
2. Or one query with all the texts, stored in an array, and use this array to output texts.

   ```
   SELECT en FROM langtexts
   ```

The table has a lot of rows with large texts.

Comment: Faster is to select all needed rows in one query and loop through the rows in PHP.

Comment: `select id, en from langtexts where id in (41, 63, 89)`. boom, done

Comment: The select queries are in different places in different files. I don't know all the exact ids before outputting the texts. I can only select all texts without ids. So this is useless for me.

Comment: Firing off a select that pulls the data you need in one operation is almost always going to outperform one select per row.  The SQL server has to parse your query, build a query plan, optimise it, perform other setup, pull the requested data from storage/cache/wherever and put it in an output buffer for every command you execute.  If you do one query that fetches 10 rows than nine rounds of all the setup/optimise/push to bufferwork are eliminated

Comment: Yes I know. It is much faster. But if I have only one query, I have to store the result in a php array. Usually 40-50 texts (from small to very large) in a page. So this needs a lot of memory.

Comment: You don't have to load the entire resultset at once (assuming you're using PDO::fetchAll ()), you can use PDO::fetch () in a loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You mention that:

> The select queries are in different places in different files. I don't know all the exact ids before outputting the texts. I can only select all texts without ids. So this is useless for me.

However, you can pass variables between different PHP scripts by storing them in the PHP **$_SESSION** variable.

I think a way to achieve what you want would be to update a **$_SESSION['GUIMessages']** with all the results of your query.

This variable, which is actually a vector containing the data in the respective database column, will then exist in memory for the remaining lifetime of the user's session.

In this scenario, you **might** save **some** processing time. However, if many users use the same language, this approach doesn't scale and I would expect it to actually yield worst results. This, since in the session would increase the overhead and decrease the performance, due to the fact that the "GUIMessages" variable will be kept **for each user**. Since sessions in PHP are stored in files by default, you'd actually be introducing extra disk I/O operations.

If the problem is convenience for you as a programmer, why don't you define a function **getGUIMessages** which takes care of the SQLQueries and receives a parameter **key** and returns an array **messages**? You then can invoke it wherever you need it without having the SQL Queries spread all over the place.

Comment: Well, I want to avoid storing texts in session, because (as you said) this will decrease performance.

I already use a function to query the texts. But this means every time I call this function I make a select query. So 50 function call = 50 query.
This is slow, but uses less memory.

If I have only one query, it is faster, but it uses more memory, because i have to store all texts in a php array.

So i don't know which one to use.

Comment: I would say that database management systems are built for this and you should therefore stick to the first approach. Basically, your two possibilities are: 

1) Access the data records you want by relying on the RDBMS which is a highly complex and efficient software solution designed to make, among others, recurrent and concurrent access to data stored on disk or otherwise as efficient as possible.

or 

2) Access the desired data by using sessions which in turn are stored in disk and end up doing that what RDBMSS do but without the support of one.

Answer (score -1):

Second one is the faster solution, you can get all the required texts in one single query and use through an indexed array where you want to use.

Comment: Why retrieve sg from a database that you do not need at the moment?